# counterexample in topology

Tags: general-topology

We know path connectedness implies connectedness . Is the other direction true or false? I ve been trying to prove it but cannot do it. I cannot find a counter-example either. math is hard.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist's_sine_curve

Comment: You know, there is a book called, emmm, [Counterexamples in Topology](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC&dq=counterexamples+in+topology&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mFOmUtftCJLLkQfWwIGwCg&redir_esc=y) ;-)

Comment: This isn't the place for a (potentially heated) semantics discussion. :\

Also, is there a university library you could check books out of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite counterexample is [Cantor's leaky tent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan).

Not only is it connected, but not path connected, removing a single point renders it completely disconnected! (Since I haven't taken topology yet, this is what prompted me to look up what "connected" really means)

Comment: Great example!!

Answer (score 0):

Look up the topologist' sine. It is not true. That is why you cannot prove it :p.

Another funky one is $\mathbb{R}_{\text{cocountable}}$.